# Changing rootviewcontroller for navigation controller dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to change `RootViewController` for `NavigationController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
But I don't know how can I do that.

I have gone through this link as well:
http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/

Here is my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *rootController=[[HomePageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageController" bundle:nil];
    navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

//    presentation=[[PresentationController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PresentationController" bundle:nil];
//    
//    navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presentation];
//    
//    presentationList=[[PresentationListController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PresentationListController" bundle:nil];
//    
//    UINavigationController *listnavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:presentationList];
//    
//    revealer=[[ZUUIRevealController alloc]initWithFrontViewController:navigationController rearViewController:listnavigation];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Right now I comment and then run application to change `rootviewcontroller`. However this is not the practical approach.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Put this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: can u explain in more detail.

Comment: What you are just doing is add the view of your navigationViewController on top of the Window... That's not what you want. You will have problems in a **near** future, for instance with  rotations.

Answer (score 1):

A navigation controller does not care what type of view controller is its root view controller, as long as it is a subclass of UIViewController. So you can just use a pointer to a UIViewController like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *rootController = nil;
    if (iWantHomePageController)
    {
        rootController = [[HomePageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if (iWantPresentationController)
    {
        rootController = [[PresentationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PresentationController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if (iWantPresentationListController)
    {
        rootController = [[PresentationListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PresentationListController" bundle:nil];
    }

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can i access these variables:iWantHomePageController,iWantPresentationController from viewcontrollers? if yes then i can set the values accordingly , and once i set the values will this event :'didFinish..' will get fired? if yes then im done. so please explain can i do this ? if yes then how?

Comment: those variables are just ones that I made up to demonstrate the ability to change the root view controller to anything you want based on the logic that you choose. You said you wanted to set them dynamically, so there must be some logic that you are using to decide what the root view controller should be. So if that logic determines that you want the home page controller, then you set rootController to HomePageController, the same for the rest.

Comment: If you want the ability to set these values from elsewhere in the app, you'll need to find a different way of trying to do what you want. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is only called when the app is initially launched and will not be called again while the app is open.

Answer (score 0):

This works really just fine for me:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

/*
    both *navigationController and *viewController are declared 
    as properties in the .h file 
*/
[self setViewController:[[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]];
[self setNavigationController:[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController]autorelease]];
[self.window setRootViewController:[self navigationController]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: thx for ur answer..by im looking to change rootviewcontroller dynamically.