# uitableviewcontroller, with xib, loaded from appdelegate, never loads?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have an ItemsViewController of type

```
  @interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController
```

Now this I call from the appdelegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like so

```
    ItemsViewController *itemsViewController = [[ItemsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemsViewController" bundle:nil];

   // Create an instance of a UINavigationController
   // its stack contains only itemsViewController
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                        initWithRootViewController:itemsViewController];

   // Place navigation controller's view in the window hierarchy
[[self window] setRootViewController:navController];


self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Now in ItemsViewController.m file I do hit this method :

```
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
      self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
      if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
  }
```

but the problem here is that it never hit the viewdidload method?? What should I look for? I am confused!!

Comment: Check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/10900817/2315974

Comment: I am not trying to change the rootvc for my navctrl, just to make it hit viewdidload. I am initi'ing it, it just never hits viewdidliad

Answer (score 1):

ok , well I found the problem, I've been doing so much editing of this project that I accidentally deleted the most important line in the beginning of the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. which is this :

```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Anyway, so I am going to kill myself now, feel free to recommend a method of death ( clorox cocktail, walk into traffic) , and if you wanna write some nice words about me to be published
in my eulogy too.

Thanks.

Comment: As penance answer three SO questions, accept your own answer, and all will be forgiven :-)

Comment: I can't, I tried, but its not possible, I showered twice so far, go way shame, go away, its useless.

Comment: You must wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer.

Comment: +1 for explaining the answer instead of deleting this and several other of your own questions and then complaining on meta about being banned. There should be a badge for owning up to your dumb mistakes so that others might someday benefit.